# Communication between servlet and JSP on JBOSS 7

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to setup a JSP that gets information from a Servlet.  I feel that I'm doing something really stupid but in my servlet I am using:

```java
HttpSession session = hreq.getSession();
hreq.setAttribute("results", "hreq value");
session.setAttribute("results","This is the value.");
hreq.getRequestDispatcher("jsp.jsp").forward(hreq, hres);
```

I can't seem to pick up either of the set values in my JSP.  I've tried using:

```
<% out.print(session.getAttribute("results"));%>
<c:out value='${results}' />
${results}
```

None of them seems to be retriving the value.

What am I doing wrong, because it's driving me up the wall?

Comment: Include full .jsp file. Include result - how does your .jsp look like. If I'll put these snippets only, it works fine and I can't reproduce it. Introduce [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import JSTL tags, as the first line, in your `.jsp` file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```